# can't embed some text in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is, that I have created a js file. In this file are some text defined.

```
channel = {
  categorie_one: "Hauptsender",
  categorie_two: "Spartensender",
  categorie_three: "Regionalsender"
}
```

Now I want to embed `categorie_one` in a other js file. That I'm doing with that code:

```
channel.categorie_one;
```

But it shows in console: `Cannot read property 'categorie_one' of undefined`, logical I have linked the file...

Im including the js files in the index.html

```
<script src="javascripts/default.js" type="text/javascript" rel="javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/resources.default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the default.js I have a methode to load the site.

```
function ChannelLoad(listview) {
     //there should be cateogrie_one
}
```

could you help me pls. Thanks in advance

Comment: How you are linking that file ?

Comment: How is `channel` defined in the the first file?

Comment: do you by any chance redefine `channel` between the place of file inclusion and its use ?

Comment: @pXL it is linked in the index.html `<script src="javascripts/resources.default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in this file is the defined text

Comment: Try calling `alert(window.channel.categorie_one);`.

Comment: @collapsar nope I don't

Comment: @AlexFilipovici it works it shows me Hauptsender :) but why it don't includes that?

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner are you calling `channel.categorie_one;` in any other js file that is included before default.js

Comment: _but why it don't includes that_, you need to document better your question. Please add the relevant parts from your code where you load the JS file.

Comment: @pXL nope I don't do that

Comment: @AlexFilipovici updateed

Comment: You need to link the JS files in the right order. In which file is `channel = {...}` defined and in which file do you access it?

Comment: `channel = {...}` is in the resources.default.js defiend and I want to acces it in the default.js @AlexFilipovici

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a semicolon to your variable definition:

```
channel = {
   categorie_one: "Hauptsender",
   categorie_two: "Spartensender",
   categorie_three: "Regionalsender"
};
```

syntactically your variable definition is a statement; if placed in a row with other statements (i assume that's where it will end up after inclusion of your js files), they have to be separated by semicolons.

Comment: +1.  It would be nice if your comment is added to the answer :)

Comment: Well, but this doesn't explain why `alert(window.channel.categorie_one)` works...

Answer (score 1):

In your html file include the scripts in the right order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="defines_object.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uses_property.js"></script>
```

Make sure the object isn't defined in a function or the scope of the object will be limited to that function.

Comment: ...and `type="text/javascript"` is optional if you are using HTML5 doctype

Comment: it isn't defined in a function.. its only the js fiel with in the channel declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.

The only thing you must be aware of is the order you include the files, all files will be executed in the order of their includes, so you should include first the file declaring the object, containing

```
channel = {
  categorie_one: "Hauptsender",
  categorie_two: "Spartensender",
  categorie_three: "Regionalsender"
}
```

then include the second file, using `channel.categorie_one;`

If this still doesn't work, please post your whole code, there's probably a scope issue (channel is declared in a local scope)

You should include your scripts in the right order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="defines_object.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uses_property.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the `channel` variable in the *resources.default.js* file and you are trying to access it in the *default.js* file, you have to reverse the order in which you link the JS files.

Try:

```
<script src="javascripts/resources.default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/default.js" type="text/javascript" rel="javascript"></script>
```